# JQuery YouTube player - multiple playlists

Tags: jquery, css, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the following jQuery YouTube player to load multiple YouTube playlists into a video player.

[jQuery YouTube Player](http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/examples/player-multiple-playlists.html)

It allows me to switch between playlists, and loads the first video on that playlist - however when I select a different video from that playlist it does not respond/load the video.

The only real difference between my page and the original is that I'm using a .php page instead of .html.

[My Page](http://www.carefusion-products.com/videos/index.php)

How do I get this functioning as it should?

Comment: Have you tried $(document).ready?

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the answer - there has been an update to the original JS which solves the problem.
https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-youtube-player/blob/9730f872f80b7796d6634fa6380dd5b521f00805/js/jquery.youtube.player.js